# Using partial backup to save up for a whole backup in EMC Networker

Tags: backup

In EMC Networker, is it possible to take advantage of a backup of part of a disk (e.g. `/root` or `C:\Windows`) to save up bandwith when later on performing a backup of the whole disk (namely `/` or `C:`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that no, it is not possible: https://community.emc.com/thread/237173